# C# client to C++ server Tcp socket connection error

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, server, client

Client is Cross Platform Application(android & ios) (C#)
Server is Windows.(C++)

I successfully connect to server but after this server recv function returns 0 seriously. But when I try to connect server with c++ client I dont get this problem.

And when client down Recv function returns 0 so I dont want to do "continue;" if recv returns 0.

I added this client code to Button. After I click to button does socket closes?

Client C# code:

```
private static async void ConnectAsTcpClient()
    {

            using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("[Client] Connecting to server");
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", 12312);
                Console.WriteLine("[Client] Connected to server");
            }

    }
```

Server C++ code:
SOCKET sock;

```
// for our thread
DWORD thread;

WSADATA wsaData;
sockaddr_in server;

// start winsock
int ret = WSAStartup(0x101, &wsaData); // use highest version of winsock avalible

if (ret != 0)
{
    return 0;
}

// fill in winsock struct ... 
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons(12312); // listen on telnet port 23

                              // create our socket
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    return 0;
}

// bind our socket to a port(port 123) 
if (bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
{
    return 0;
}

// listen for a connection  
if (listen(sock, 5) != 0)
{
    return 0;
}

// socket that we snedzrecv data on
SOCKET client;

sockaddr_in from;
int fromlen = sizeof(from);
printf("Server Started\n");
client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen);
printf("Client connected\r\n");

while (true)
{
    res = recv(current_client, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); // recv cmds


    // multi Thread
    Sleep(30);

    if (res == 0 || res >= 150)
    {
        printf("Recv Failed! = %d\n", res);
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The client doesn't write anything, instead it lets the `tcpClient` object go out of scope, which disconnects, leading to `recv` returning `0` in the server.

By the way, you forgot to check for actual errors from the `recv` call (when `res == SOCKET_ERROR`).

Comment: I think problem is at client because when I close application on Android server keeps receiving 0. So after connection client socket disconeccts but IDK how to fix it.

Comment: @ismetJM If `recv` returns `0`, then it means that the other end has closed the connection. You must then close your end of the connection, and go back waiting for a new connection. The behavior of `recv` returning `0` is *well* documented, and any good networking tutorial should have told you what that means and what to do.